# Foreground Service getting terminated when Application is killed

Tags: android, service

I have been trying to get the Service to run in the background for that I have implemented the foreground approach still its killing the app. 
I need this service to return me the location of the user even if the application is killed.

MainActivity.kt

```
private fun kickStartService(){
        var intent = Intent(this , LocationService::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
        intent.putExtra("extra" , "extra")
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService( this , intent)
//        startService( intent)

    }
```

LocationService.kt

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        myNotification(intent)
        mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build()

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        if (!mGoogleApiClient!!.isConnected) {
            mGoogleApiClient!!.connect()
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }



    fun myNotification( intent : Intent?){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            var extra = intent?.getStringExtra("extra")
            var pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
                Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
                }
            var notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                .setContentText(extra)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker("Ticker Text")
                .build()
            startForeground(1, notification)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `WorkManager` instead of Service.

Comment: WorkManager work after the interval of 15 minutes at minimum which will not be efficient for live tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, My bad, I was using Xiaomi Mi Mix 2 and so it happens that Mi does not let you start a foreground service if you have auto start off from the app settings in app manager. Once I turned it on, my foreground service is working like a charms.